# able to import module but not things from it

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, pycharm, python-packaging

I am on mac (first time) and using pycharm and visual code.

On pycharm, I am using a venv, have installed scapy and can see it is installed in the interpreter package manager and there is no red line under "import scapy". the issue arises when I try and import anything from that package "from scapy import UDP" or use anything in scapy "scapy.UDP". ----respective errors shown below.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'UDP' from 'scapy' (/Users/{KEVIN}/PycharmProjects/UDP/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scapy/__init__.py)

AttributeError: module 'scapy' has no attribute 'UDP'
```

As a side not I tried using visual code and system python, and the code runs with no issues, but i cant right click on UDP() and jump to the class definition it says not definition found? I feel like this has to be a mac related issue but i can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is not directly under scapy, you need to do

```
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP
```

then you can right click on UDP() and jump to the class definition.

Following two imports worked for me as well :

```
venv$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scapy.ansmachine import AnsweringMachine
>>> from scapy.all import UDP
>>>
```

Please double check you scapy installation.

Comment: Thank you @Philippe! I spent way to much time for something so trivial. This solved all issues in both IDEs. but can you explain why "from scapy.all import UDP" doesnt work?

Comment: This answer only worked once, running it again produced error: ImportError: cannot import name 'AnsweringMachine' from partially initialized module 'scapy.ansmachine' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score -1):

Try:
`from scapy.all import *` from https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html

Does this work?

Comment: So it will run in pycharm venv, but it still doesn't see the function UDP(). normally I could click on UDP() to see the constructor but instead I see "Cannot find reference 'UDP' in 'imported module scapy | imported module scapy | __init__.py' "

Comment: If I do "from scapy.all import UDP" it still runs but it shows red line under UDP that when hovered above shows, "Cannot find reference 'UDP' in 'all.py' "